# CSS table width rule

Tags: css, richfaces

I am supporting a legacy application.

In the CSS there is the following rule:

```
.dashboard-panel table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

So basically there are many panels, and for all tables in them the `width` is set to `100%`.

Now the problem: in a dashboard panel I have put a calendar control from an external library (richfaces).  This calendar control is using a table for displaying the days. And this `width:100%` is affecting the calendar table.

Example:

```
<div class="dashboard-panel">
    <div id="content">
       <table id="table1"> //this is ok
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table id="richfacesCalendarTable"> //this not ok
                  </table>
               </td>  
            </tr> 
       </table>        
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the proper solution here?

I don't want to go through every panel in this application and put a separate style there.

Comment: Without being given any HTML to see where these things are everyone has to guess. Try  `.dashboard-panel > table`

Comment: If you don't mind dropping old browser support, try [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:not) pseudo class.

Comment: @popnoodles - I think my question is clear, but I will put some more HTML.

Comment: the question is clear. Where table lies in `.dashboard-panel` is anyone's guess

Comment: i think table in table is not permitted or recommended : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table#Usage_context but still works

Comment: @Aspiring Aquib - Actually the richfaces table is inside a `<tr>` of the outside table.

Comment: @PetarMinchev now its good :D

Comment: @PetarMinchev http://jsfiddle.net/P4vYT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mabye if you add something like that into end of your css:

```
.dashboard-panel table#richfacesCalendarTable {
    width: your_desired_width_px !important;
}
```

or

```
.dashboard-panel table#richfacesCalendarTable {
    width: auto !important;
    display: table !important;
}
```

Hard to say for sure as this is only a small portion of HTML and CSS code you provided. There can be other elements that affects your result.

Comment: I ended up using the first solution. Thanks!